# React Apollo testing: MockProvider takes a long time when running tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-apollo

I'm using `MockedProvider` from `@apollo/react-testing` in a around 20 tests and each test in isolation runs in about 2.5seconds but when run together some of them randomly take 6-8s

I really cannot wrap my head around this as the "slow" tests are always different and the order in which the tests are executed is always different.

Every test has the following structure

```
import React from 'react'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing'
import { render, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react'
import MyComponent from './'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup)
  it('queries for and displays MyComponent', async () => {
    const cmp = render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
          <MyComponent />
      </MockedProvider>,
      { wrapper: MemoryRouter }
    )
    expect(cmp.getByText('something')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Have you ever had a similar experience? Any idea what i could check?
I'm on 
`react v16.9.0`
`@apollo/react-testing v3.1.3`

Answer (score -1):

Ran into a similar issue. The problem for me was too many records being returned by a specific query.

I had about 4,000 mocked results being returned as an array and tests took about 4 - 5 seconds to complete. Now returning 10 results, they are down to about 75ms.

Something that helped me narrow this down was profiling one test using Chrome's remote debugging feature for Node. Kent C Dodds did a quick video on it which helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB2g-o39upo